# Horizontal scrollbar for Ext-js 4.2 grid

Tags: extjs

My Ext-js 4.2 grid is now showing up horizontal scroll bar. I tried to google for the same and lot of people have different opnion for it . Can someone please tell me how can I get horizontal scrollbar for the grid.
Thanks
Samir

---

```
      function setWidthForGrid(grid) {
    var containerId = 'centerPanel';
    var widthOfPanel = Ext4.getCmp(containerId).getWidth();

        var columnCount = grid.view.panel.columns.length,
         lastColumnW = grid.view.panel.columns[columnCount - 1].width,
         w = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
          w += grid.view.panel.columns[i].width;
        }
        if (w > widthOfPanel) {

        w = widthOfPanel;
        grid.view.setWidth(1200);
        grid.view.panel.setWidth(1900);
        grid.doLayout(true,true);
        }
        else {
        lastColumnW += widthOfPanel - w;
        grid.view.panel.columns[columnCount - 1].setWidth(lastColumnW);
        }



}
```

However it seems this is not serving the purpose. I as well tried to call doLayout after changing the width however it did not work for me. Some people saying that its a bug with EXT-JS 4.2. Is that really the case ?
Any white paper , link will greatly be appriciated.
Thanks
Samir

Comment: can we see your code?

Comment: I tried calling below mentioned function on store load. It sets the width explicitly . But it did not work for me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys...its my mistake . I was setting forecefit : true in the grid config. Removing that caused the grid to have a horizontal scroll bar.
Thanks
Samir